# for in loop not updating elements

Tags: swift

I'm sure this is really simple. But I'm not sure what's going on. I've taken a break from swift and just getting back into it with Swift three.

I'm expecting when the play button is clicked and the `isPlaying` is true that the people in my `currentLineup[0]` have their values updated. Which they do seem to do when the function is called. But when I call `currentLieneup[0][0]` the values seem to be back to `isPlaying: false, timeCameOn: 0` as noted in the log?

I have a the following:

```
var currentLineup: [[Player]] = []

    @IBAction func playPause(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // change icon to play or pause
    isPlaying = isPlaying ? false : true
    // set player.timeCameOn to current time or back to 0
    updatePlayerGameStartTime(gameInProgress: isPlaying)
    print(currentLineup[0][0])
}

    // When play button pressed, make sure players timeCameOn updated
func updatePlayerGameStartTime(gameInProgress: Bool){
    if gameInProgress {
        for var player in currentLineup[0]{ // Playing
            player.isPlaying = true
            player.timeCameOn = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
            print(player)
        }

        for var player in currentLineup[1]{ // Subs
            player.isPlaying = false
            player.timeCameOn = 0
        }
    }
}
```

I note in my log the following:

```
Player(name: "Player 1", isPlaying: true, timeCameOn: 1488304289, currentPlayedTime: 0)
Player(name: "Player 2", isPlaying: true, timeCameOn: 1488304289, currentPlayedTime: 0)
Player(name: "Player 3", isPlaying: true, timeCameOn: 1488304289, currentPlayedTime: 0)
Player(name: "Player 4", isPlaying: true, timeCameOn: 1488304289, currentPlayedTime: 0)
Player(name: "Player 1", isPlaying: false, timeCameOn: 0, currentPlayedTime: 0)
```

**updated**
I'm setting the initial `currentLineup` by calling in viewdidload() a function called `createInitialCurrentPlayingList()`.

```
createInitialCurrentPlayingList(listOfPlayers: [Player]){
  for player in listOfPlayers {
    if startingLineup.count < 4 {
      startingLineup.append(player)
    } else {
       startingSubs.append(player) 
     } 
  }
   currentLineup.insert(startingLineup, at:0)
   currentLineup.insert(startingSubs, at: 1)
}

// declarations of vars
startingLineup: [Player] = []
startingSubs: [Player] = []
currentLineup: [[Player]] = []
```

Comment: Are you sure Player 1 doesn't exist at both `currentLineup[0][0]` and `currentLineup[1][0]` ?

Comment: Also, is Player a Class or a Struct?

Comment: Hi @PEEJWEEJ. It's a class and I've confirmed that Player doesn't exist either.

Comment: I'm still guessing `currentLineup[0][0]` and `currentLineup[1][0]` are the same object reference. Post how you're setting currentLineup or examine the memory locations.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I've updated my question with the required piece.

Comment: is `Player` a typo? or is that defined somewhere? (for `append(Player)`)

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Defined in it's own class

Comment: What's the Type of `startingLineup` and `startingSubs`? based on your code, it looks like you're appending a Type reference of Player. (please just include the declarations)

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Updated with declarations

Comment: `.append(Player)` doesn't make any sense based on what you've posted. It would append `Player.Type` to an array of `Player`. Do you have some variable named "Player"?

Comment: Player in that case, is a typo. When I was copying from my mac (with no internet) to my desktop. append(player), is me putting that player into the array. It loads exactly how I expect. and it seems to update the start times when I click on the play button. But I don't understand why it then seems to revert back to to it's initial set up of `Player(name: "Player X", isPlaying: false, timeCameOn: 0, currentPlayedTime: 0)`

Comment: How are you defining `listOfPlayers` ?

Comment: I have a SampleData.swift file, that just creates an array of Player objects, it's var name is `playersData`. So I call the function  like this `createInitialCurrentPlayingList(listOfPlayers: playersData)`

Comment: Make sure that's creating distinct objects for each array index. (or post the code).

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ They're distinct, I added a createdAt Timestamp and it's the same for all the objects

Comment: If it's measured in milliseconds, each createdAt should be different.

Comment: BTW, if all the objects were the same, they would also have the same time stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a value type issue

Please try this, it assigns the subarray back to `currentLineup`.

```
var firstLineup = currentLineup[0]
for player in firstLineup { // Playing
      player.isPlaying = true
      player.timeCameOn = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
      print(player)
}
currentLineup[0] = firstLineup
```